# Jenkinsfile check if build triggered by push or merge request

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Right now I have configured jenkins gitlab connection and gitlab webhook to trigger jenkins jobs.

I would like to create Jenkinsfile where some tasks are executed only if build was triggered by push and some others only if build was triggered by merge request. I use pipeline jobs. Is that possible?

BUILD_CAUSE variable shows nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Jenkins Builtin Functions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions).
You are probably looking for `changeRequest`:

> Executes the stage if the current build is for a "change request" (a.k.a. Pull Request > on GitHub and Bitbucket, Merge Request on GitLab or Change in Gerrit etc.). When no 
>   parameters are passed the stage runs on every change request, for example: when { 
>   changeRequest() }.

Comment: When using GitLab, the changeRequest function doesn't seem to work, even though the documentation you linked to states otherwise.

I ended up checking if gitlabMergeRequestId was set

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is possible. Your best bet is to write 2 separate jobs. 1 which triggers on a push event and other which triggers on merge reqeust only. Another thing that you can do is write a separate webhook which sends different parameters according to the push/merge event and configure your jenkins job with conditional BuildStep plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the gitlab jenkins plugin you can check if the env variable gitlabMergeRequestId is set not.

Answer (score -1):

- If you are in a `when` block, you can use `changeRequest` variable as described [here](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative/)
- If you are in a `script` block or in any other part of the pipeline, you can create a variable like this in the first stage and use it everywhere

---

```
def isPullRequest = false

pipeline {
  agent {
    // ....
  }
  stages {
    stage('First stage') {
      steps {
        script {
          isPullRequest = env.CHANGE_ID != null
        }
      }
    }
    // other stages...
  }
}
```